# Matching/approximating string words with textInput() (R shiny)

Tags: r, user-interface, dplyr, input, shiny

I am building a basic search tool where someone can enter their job title, monthly wage, and city, and as an output they can learn how their wages compare to the median wage in their area controlling for their job title/occupation.

Here is a data example:

```
#dput(df[80:100,c(1,2,4,5)])
```

```
structure(list(grp = c("Senior Accountant", "Driver", "Admin Assistant", 
"Data scientist", "Receptionist", "Barista", "Accountant", 
"Data analyst", "Sales Executive", "Sales Representative", "Data analyst", 
"Account Manager", "Marketing Manager", "Data analyst", "Secretary", 
"Data analyst", "Barista", "Waiter", "Senior Accountant", "Senior Accountant", 
"Data analyst"), monthly_income = c(4000, 2500, 3500, 
4900, 4500, 5000, 5000, 4000, 7000, 2500, 4000, 25688.33, 10000, 
8000, 4000, 4500, 5500, 2500, 4500, 7000, 15000), location = c("Portland", 
"Portland", "Seattle", "Seattle", "Seattle", "Seattle", "Georgetown", "Georgetown", 
"Dammam", "Georgetown", "Georgetown", "Portland", "Portland", "Portland", "Georgetown", 
"Seattle", "Seattle", "Georgetown", "Portland", "Portland", "Portland"), 
    qualifications = c("HS", "no_qual_preference", "BA", "BA", 
    "no_qual_preference", "no_qual_preference", "BA", "no_qual_preference", 
    "BA", "no_qual_preference", "no_qual_preference", "BA", "BA", 
    "BA", "no_qual_preference", "no_qual_preference", "no_qual_preference", 
    "no_qual_preference", "no_qual_preference", "no_qual_preference", 
    "no_qual_preference")), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

One issue I have with my current code is that users only receive a response if their job title matches the exact spelling/words of job titles in my df. Ideally, I want to approximate job titles where something like "Senior Financial Accountant" would be approximated/matched to "Senior Accountant" in the df, but with my code below, the user has to type the exact job title, otherwise, they receive an "NA" response.

```
library(shiny)
#library(readxl)


ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("grp", "Occupation"),
  numericInput("monthly_income", "Monthly Pay", value = 0),
  textInput("location", "City"),
  textInput("qualifications", "Qualifications"),
  #numericInput("yrs_experience", "Years of Experience", value = 0),
  actionButton("compare_btn", "Compare Salary"),
  verbatimTextOutput("comparison_results"))

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$compare_btn, {
    user_Occupation <- input$grp
    user_monthly_pay <- input$monthly_income
    user_location <- input$location
    user_qualification <- input$qualifications

    # data frame named "salary_test_data" with columns .....
    filtered_data <- salary_test_data[salary_test_data$grp == user_Occupation  & 
                                        salary_test_data$location == user_location &
                                        salary_test_data$qualifications == user_qualification , ] 

    
    if (nrow(filtered_data) > 0) {
      comparison_results <- ifelse(user_monthly_pay >= median(filtered_data$monthly_income),
                                   "Your monthly salary is above the median income of workers employed in your profession & city ",
                                   "Your monthly salary is below the median income of workers employed in your profession & city")
    } else {
      comparison_results <- "No data found for the given job title and/or city"
    }
    
    output$comparison_results <- renderText({
      comparison_results
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I would think that asking people to select from a predefined list of job titles is likely to be much, much easier than trying to do fuzzy matching like this.

Comment: I agree with you, but with the beta version of this tool, I was told from some developers that I should introduce fuzzy matching thus making it more similar to a classic Google search. Moreover, I noticed that when some user enter "Data analysis" instead of "Data analyst", which produces an "NA" result when the two jobs are likely very similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I realized that `fedmatch` just uses the `stringdist` package, so we can use this directly. The function is called `amatch` and there is also `ain` (returning a logical):

```
filter <- stringdist::ain(d$grp, "Senior Financial Accountant", maxDist = 10)
d[filter, ]
```

Giving:

```
  grp               monthly_income location qualifications    
  <chr>                      <dbl> <chr>    <chr>             
1 Senior Accountant           4000 Portland HS                
2 Senior Accountant           4500 Portland no_qual_preference
3 Senior Accountant           7000 Portland no_qual_preference
```

You will have to tweak the algorithm and maxDist to your needs. This resource should be useful: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringdist/versions/0.9.10/topics/stringdist-metrics

**I will leave the old answer as is:**

How about using the `fedmatch` package? I assume your data set is called `d` in the following and that you have `fetmatch` installed and loaded:

```
# ID var is required for merge_plus, please adjust to your needs
d$id1 <- seq(nrow(d))

# this is the search string of the user, also needs an id
d2 <- data.frame(grp = "Senior Financial Accountant", id2 = 1)

# now we merge by grp with custom fuzzy matching
d_merged <- merge_plus(
  d, d2, by = "grp", match_type = "fuzzy", 
  unique_key_1 = "id1", 
  unique_key_2 = "id2",
  fuzzy_settings = build_fuzzy_settings(method = "wgt_jaccard", maxDist = .5)
)
d_merged$matches
```

Giving me:

```
   id2 id1 monthly_income location     qualifications             grp_1                       grp_2 tier
1:   1   1           4000 Portland                 HS Senior Accountant Senior Financial Accountant  all
2:   1  19           4500 Portland no_qual_preference Senior Accountant Senior Financial Accountant  all
3:   1  20           7000 Portland no_qual_preference Senior Accountant Senior Financial Accountant  all
```

It will require some tweaking, but I believe the result is what you want (`Senior Accountant` is matched with `Senior Financial Accountant`).

Comment: Thanks, that's a good start! Although I tried with a few job entries and I keep receiving the same error message "Error in wgt_jaccard(corpus$word, corpus$log_inv_freq, data1[[by.x]],  : 
  Expecting a single value: [extent=0]."

Comment: Not sure what causes this problem, but I simplified the answer. Does this work for you?